# Default windows theme specific BorderBrush for the Menu control

Tags: wpf, menu

How do I get the default windows theme specific BorderBrush for the Menu control? For example, I can get the Background colour for menu using `Background="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuBrush}"`.

Answer (score 0):

What about `ActiveBorderBrush` or `SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush`?

[image: Windows Theme Brushes]

Taken From: [MSDN WPF Team Blog - SystemColors Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx)

Comment: This seems to be a very good start! However, in Classic style the borderbrush kinda turns to white and gray in Aero. So ActiveBorderBrush or SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush dont really fit in there. What does WPF use internally...do they use something static or is it something hardcoded? Since it changes on theme, it has to be something static! But what exactly is that?!!